# Jquery autocomplete returns result, but result is not showing anything

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am having problems with jQuery autocomplete. I am using function below, to get results for the `inputACCO_KEY`.
Problem is, that I don't see results - but obviously something is returned from function, because I see autocomplete form below div - but is is always empty. Sometimes it's longer, sometimes shorter (depends on how many results are returned), but it's always empty. If I select something from that empty table, result shown in the input is also empty.

Function:

```
$("#inputACCO_KEY").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: "/wsSearchCAMERC/GetCAACCOSearchAll/",          
          data: {
            prefixText: $("#inputACCO_KEY").val(),
            count: 30
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            response($(data).map(function (item, i) {              
              return {                
                label: item.First,
                value: item.Second
              };
            })
            );
          },
          error: function (data) {
            alert('error');
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function (event, ui) {        
        log("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id);
      }
    });
  });
```

[image]

Result is of type:

```
    ["{"First":"BOŠTJA S.P.","Second":"160001670"}", 
"{"First":"GOLF KLUB","Second":"110001615"}", "{"First":"IRENA","Second":"150001322"}"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select method must return false. Otherwise, it doesn't work as supposed.

Full working example:

```
$("#inputACCO_KEY").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: "/wsSeCAMERC/GetCA/",
          data: {
            prefixText: $("#inputACCO_KEY").val(),
            count: 30
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item, i) {
              return {
                label: item.cACCO_NME,
                value: item.iACCO_KEY
              };
            })
            );
          },
          error: function (data) {
            alert('error!');
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#inputACCO_KEY").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#iACCO_KEY").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Result is of type:
>
> ["{"First":"BOŠTJA S.P.","Second":"160001670"}",
> "{"First":"GOLF KLUB","Second":"110001615"}", "{"First":"IRENA","Second":"150001322"}"]

That sounds very strange. I assume the inner string separator are escaped, so that you have an array of string.
If this is your case you need to change the map function to:

```js
var data = ["{\"First\":\"BOŠTJA S.P.\",\"Second\":\"160001670\"}", "{\"First\":\"GOLF KLUB\",\"Second\":\"110001615\"}", "{\"First\":\"IRENA\",\"Second\":\"150001322\"}"];
var result = $(data).map(function (idx, ele) {
    var item = JSON.parse(ele);
    return {
        label: item.First,
        value: item.Second
    };
});

console.log(result);

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var data = ["{\"First\":\"BOŠTJA S.P.\",\"Second\":\"160001670\"}", "{\"First\":\"GOLF KLUB\",\"Second\":\"110001615\"}", "{\"First\":\"IRENA\",\"Second\":\"150001322\"}"];
        response($(data).map(function (idx, ele) {
            var item = JSON.parse(ele);
            return {
                label: item.First,
                value: item.Second
            };
        }));
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```